# MySQL JOIN and WHERE - What's wrong my with query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch some user data from my two tables. Any idea what's wrong? Any help is appreciated.

> **Error message:**
>
> Unknown column 'a3p_user_fields.user_id' i tabel field list

**My tables:**

```
**a3p_user_fields**

user_id, 
field_title, 
field_job_title, 
field_education, 
field_experience, 
field_hourly_wage, 
field_support, 
field_fee, 
field_description,

**a3p_usermeta**

umeta_id, 
user_id, 
meta_key, 
meta_value
```

**My query:**

```
    SELECT `a3p_user_fields.user_id`, `a3p_user_fields.field_job_title`, 
   `a3p_user_fields.field_education`, `a3p_user_fields.field_experience`, 
   `a3p_user_fields.field_hourly_wage`, `a3p_usermeta.meta_key` FROM 
   `a3p_user_fields` INNER JOIN `a3p_usermeta` 
   ON `a3p_user_fields.user_id` = 'a3p_usermeta.user_id` 
   WHERE `a3p_user_fields.field_title` = 'Gartner' 
   AND `a3p_usermeta.meta_key` = 'candidate_flexjob' AND `a3p_usermeta.metavalue` = 'Ja' 
  ORDER BY `a3p_user_fields.user_id` ASC
```

Comment: You do have an issue with 'meta_value' and 'metavalue'.

Comment: Thanks, that worked together with Rahul's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in below lines I believe which is a quoting issue

```
ON `a3p_user_fields.user_id` = 'a3p_usermeta.user_id`
```

You meant it to be

```
ON `a3p_user_fields`.`user_id` = `a3p_usermeta`.`user_id`
```

As well your way of selecting the columns are not correct like

```
SELECT `a3p_user_fields.user_id`
```

You should quote the table and column names separately

```
SELECT `a3p_user_fields`.`user_id`
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to edit my query, but I'm still getting this error. Unkown column: 'a3p_usermeta.metavalue' in table where clause. Edit: Works now! You and user3741598's answers did the magic :)